# How to copy the content (except first line) of all files in a folder to a destination file?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a bunch of files in a folder. They all start with a header. I want to copy the content of all of them to a single file. I want the header not to be copied.
I have made the following bash script

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

FILES=$1
DESTINATION=$2
files=(${FILES})
echo $files
for f in $files
do
    echo 'File '$f
    awk 'NR>=2' $f >> $DESTINATION
done
```

I call this file using `./copy.sh ./folder/*.csv newfile.csv`. But as a result it copies only the first file. Particularly, I can see that the list contains only one file. Any advise?

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -s '1d' ./folder/*.csv >newfile.csv`

Answer (score 2):

No need to loop in bash as awk can work with multiple files. Just use this simplified script:

```bash
dest="$1"
shift

awk 'FNR > 1' "$@" > "$dest"
```

And call your script as:

```bash
./copy.sh newfile.csv ./folder/*.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -q -n +2 ./folder/*.csv > newfile.csv
```

---

*man tail*

```
-q, --quiet, --silent
     never output headers giving file names

-n, --lines=[+]NUM
     output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; 
     or use -n +NUM to output starting with line NUM
```